# VBA Dynamic Named Range as Listbox RowSource Error

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, listbox, named-ranges

I have a dynamic named range that returns a list (array) of some values that are not assigned but once all values are assigned the list returns #N/A

Formula (Array):

> =INDEX(EquipTable[Equip], MATCH(0,EquipTable[Flag],0), 1):INDEX(EquipTable[Equip],
>   MATCH(0,EquipTable[Flag],0)+COUNTIF(EquipTable[Flag],0)-1, 1)

Problem is that I am using this Ranged named as a Listbox.RowSource and I can't find a way to check for the value of the named range or even to check whether its returns errors or not.

I used:

`Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Names("UnassignedEquipment"))`

But its always returning False

I also used:

`IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Names("UnassignedEquipment"))`

and

`IsError(ActiveWorkbook.Names("UnassignedEquipment"))`

Comment: I have a form that has 2 Listbox, the "Unassigned Equipment" is added to one of those Listboxes, it is important to let the user know that there are equipment that are still not assigned, for info assigned and unassigned to a table "Valves Table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use IFERROR in the formula used for the named range so that if the named range doesn't return anything, it refers to a specific range/cell.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(EquipTable[Equip], MATCH(0,EquipTable[Flag],0), 1):INDEX(EquipTable[Equip], MATCH(0,EquipTable[Flag],0)+COUNTIF(EquipTable[Flag],0)-1, 1),A1)
```

Here A1 is the cell which the named range would refer if nothing a valid range is not returned by the formula. Change A1 in the formula as per your requirement.